# Programmatically Start Dragging JSlider Thumb

Tags: java, swing, mouse, drag, jslider

I have created a JSlider. I want to be able to click anywhere on the slider and have the thumb move to the location of the mouse and start dragging (normally you have to click on the thumb). I was able to have the thumb move to the mouse location by adding a mouse listener with the method:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    slider.setValue(((BasicSliderUI) slider.getUI()).valueForXPosition(e.getX()));
}
```

The problem is that once I press the mouse button, then move it, the thumb stays in place. Is there some way to programmatically initiate the dragging?

Comment: [MouseMotionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html) and monitor the mouseDragged event

Comment: But that doesn't initiate the default dragging. I have it set to snap to tick marks, something it usually does after the mouse is released. If I just monitor the mouseDragged event, it'll snap before the mouse is released.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to initiate the dragging by calling the mousePressed event of the SliderUI's trackListener. I created a class that extends BasicSliderUI and has a mouse listener with the event:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    slider.setValue(valueForXPosition(e.getX()));
    trackListener.mousePressed(e);
}
```